# combinatorics sum 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

Player 1 and Player 2 both start with 100 rupees. Each round of a game consists of the
following:
Both players choose a number randomly and independently from 1 to 5. If both players
choose the same number, then Player 1 gives rupees 10 to Player 2. Otherwise, Player
2 gives rupees 10 to Player 1. Then the expected amount of money Player 1 will be left
with after playing 10 rounds of this game is
A. 120 B. 100 C. 50 D. 160

My Approach:
Required expectation for 1 round= (1/5*1*(-10)+1/5*1/4*(10))=-1.5 rupees
Therefore Expectation for 10 rounds = -1.5*10=-15 rupees

So the player 1 will be left with 100-15= 85 rs.

But this does not match any of the answer options.

Comment: How did you get 1/5*1/4*(10) ?

Comment: Probability Player 1 chooses a number from 5 numbers is 1/5 and 2nd player can choose from any of the 4 numbers except number chosen by player 1.So probability is 1/5*1/4. and hence expectation is 1/5*1/4*10

Answer (score 3):

I think the term in your expectation for winning should be read $\dfrac 15 \cdot \dfrac 14 \cdot 10$, but I don't see how you got that.  Player $1$'s chance for winning is $\dfrac 45$, so that term should be $\dfrac 45 \cdot 10$

Comment: how did you get 4/5 as probability?

Comment: Probability Player 1 chooses a number from 5 numbers is 1/5 and 2nd player can choose from any of the 4 numbers except number chosen by player 1.So probability is 1/5*1/4. and hence expectation is 1/5*1/4*10

Comment: No, once Player 1 chooses a number the chance that Player 2's doesn't match is $4/5$.  If Player 1 chooses $1$, Player 2 can choose $2,3,4,$ or $5$ and Player $1$ wins.  The chance Player 1 wins is $1-\frac 15=\frac 45$

Comment: @KrishanuDasgupta: I see where your expression came from, but I think (just from a pedagogical point of view) you're jumping into probabilities too quickly.  What you should be doing first is thinking about what the successes or failures look like: What does a mismatch look like?  It looks like 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-1, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, etc.  How many mismatches are there?  What is the probability that any given pair of numbers is a mismatch?  Given that all distinct pairs are equally likely, that probability is the number of mismatches divided by the number of pairs: $20/25 = 4/5$.

Comment: Thanks Brian...Yes I was jumping into conclusion way too fast.I missed the fact that the individual probabilities need to be added to get the final result..so my result was wrong.The way you described is another way of looking into the problem...Thanks a lot....cheers..:)

Answer (score 2):

The expected gain for player $1$ per turn is $\frac{1}{5} \cdot (-10) + \frac{4}{5} \cdot (10) = 6$. After $10$ turns, that's $60$ rupees gained. On top of the original $100$, that's $160$ rupees total.

One way to think of the probability is to first assume Player $2$ picks a number. Then the probability that player $1$ picks that number is $\frac{1}{5}$. The probability of not picking that number is $\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Should not we take the probability of player 2 into account?Sorry I might be wrong but the chance of player 1 losing should be 1/5(probability of player 2 picking a number)*1/5(probability of player 1 picking the same number) and the chance of player 1 winning 1/5*4/5???

Comment: You may be thinking of it this way: P(both players choose 1) = (1/5)(1/5), P(both players choose 2) = (1/5)(1/5), and so on. But we're after the probability that both players pick the same number *in general*, and that could be any of the choices: It could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. When you have a chain of "or"s like that, you can add those probabilities. And 5 * (1/5)(1/5) = 1/5. But the "quick shortcut" is thinking of it as if one player has already selected something and you want to know the probability that you pick what he picked. Both get you the same answer.